# Floating on 2nd pack of Paragraph not applying - CSS - Floating

Tags: html, css, css-float

I'm following a coursera lesson (John Hopkins University) and have reached the CSS lecture about floating.

Instead of just changing the CSS application on the first set of paragraph 1 2 3 4, I would like to apply the modification of the floating example on an additional set of paragraph 5 6 7 8.

```css
div {
  background-color: #00FFFF;
}

#div2 {
  background-color: #00FFFF;
}

p {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#P1 {
  background-color: #A52A2A;
  float: right
}

#P2 {
  background-color: #DEB887;
}

#P3 {
  background-color: #5F9EA0;
}

#P4 {
  background-color: #FF7F50;
}

section {
  background-color: rgb(52, 143, 36);
  color: black;
  font-size: 120%;
  text-align: left;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 10px;
  border: solid black;
  padding: 20px;
}

p #div2 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

#P5 {
  background-color: #A52A2A;
}

#P6 {
  background-color: #DEB887;
}

#P7 {
  background-color: #5F9EA0;
}

#P8 {
  background-color: #FF7F50;
}
```

```html
<H1>Floating Part One</H1>
<div>
  <p id="P1"></p>
  <p id="P2"></p>
  <p id="P3"></p>
  <p id="P4"></p>
</div>

<H1>Floating Part 2</H1>
<div id="div2">
  <p id="P5"></p>
  <p id="P6"></p>
  <p id="P7"></p>
  <p id="P8"></p>

</div>
<section>We've removed the float right part and just make every paragraph float to the left with a margin right 10px </section>
```

I've tried to make all paragraphs nested in "Div2" to be applied an all floating left,
which should diminish the size of the Div2 and put all the Paragraphs 5 6 7 8 to be lined in accordance with the class. But I'm not reaching it.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use `flex`. On positioning things with css always avoid `float` and use `flex` or `grid` instead. You can achieve this by wrapping each column inside one div and both columns inside another div. With flex you can easily define the alignment and space between elements and how they should behave when building responsive layouts:

This how I fixed:

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Home</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <!--
      Need a visual blank slate?
      Remove all code in `styles.css`!
    -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
    <script type="module" src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div>
        <h1>Floating Part One</h1>
        <div>
          <p id="P1">Some text</p>
          <p id="P2">Some text</p>
          <p id="P3">Some text</p>
          <p id="P4">Some text</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div>
        <h1>Floating Part 2</h1>
        <div id="div2">
          <p id="P5">Some more text</p>
          <p id="P6">Some more text</p>
          <p id="P7">Some more text</p>
          <p id="P8">Some more text</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <section class="footer">
      We've removed the float right part and just make every paragraph float to
      the left with a margin right 10px
    </section>
  </body>
</html>
```

On the css I just added the following class:

```
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 10px;
}
```

here you have a functioning Stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-dt16qz?file=index.html